# Validate ComboBox using validation rules in WPF and MMVM

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I am trying to validate a combobox selected item in WPF/MVVM using validation rules and cannot get it to work.  I have this XAML:

```
   <ComboBox Grid.Row="2"  Margin="0,0,0,5" Grid.Column="1" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Tiers}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultErrorTemplate}"
DisplayMemberPath="Description"
SelectedValuePath="Id">        
<ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <Binding Path="SelectedSchoolProgramTierCombined.TierId" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
        Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <validationRules:RequiredValidationRule/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedItem>
```

I have a SelectedSchoolProgramTierCombined property setter and getting in my ViewModel.

My validation rule is:

```
 public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value == null || object.Equals(value, string.Empty))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "The field is mandatory.");
        else
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Doesn't your ValidationRule get entered? Doesn't your Validate-method do what it should? Isn't the ValidationError-Template displayed correctly on the UI?

Comment: Does SelectedSchoolProgramTierCombined implement IDataErrorInfo? Also make sure to set NotifyOnValidationErrors=true as well.